# Use Results of Find Command to Call vi

Tags: command-line

Is there a way that I can pipe the output of this command (assuming there is only one file found) to vi.  I want to find this command, and then call it up in vi.

Thanks.

```
find . -name 'id.properties'
```

Answer (score 9):

To edit the **files** printed by `find`:

```
find . -name 'id.properties' -exec vi {} +
```

In plain English, this finds paths in the current directory (`.`) and all subdirectories with a base name of `id.properties`. With these files it **runs** a `vi file1 file2 [...]` command (`-exec vi {} +`). If there are very many files (typically thousands), it might even run more than one `vi` command, each with a bunch of files, to be able to fit the commands into the maximum command length of your system. To force it to run the command for *each* file you could use `\;` instead of `+`.

To edit the **text** printed by `find`:

```
find . -name 'id.properties' | vi -
```

This **writes** the paths (relative to the current directory) of any files found (because by default `find` has a hidden `-print` at the end) to its standard output, which is [connected (`|`)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Pipes) to `vi`'s standard input. `vi`, in turn, reads from standard input (`-`) and shows that as a file to be edited.

Comment: Can you explain the commands a bit more? Why the `+` in the first one and the empty braces and why the `-` in the second one?

Answer (score 0):

You can push the output in a textfile and open it with vi.

```
find . -name 'id.properties' >> /home/<user>/find.txt
vi /home/<user>/find.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716470/can-you-mass-edit-all-files-returned-in-a-grep) seems most straight forward. For your case it would be:

```
vim $(find . -name 'id.properties')
```

Comment: -1: This could easily blow up with spaces in paths. The `exec` version is far better.